# Get html content by id selector from external file using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, templates

I want to know if there any possibility to get an element (HTML content) from an external HTML file using the ID selector of this element

The external file (`template.html`):

```
<div id="id1">Content 1 </div>
<div id="id2">Content 2 </div>
```

Is there any process like this :

the current file (`index.html`)

```
<script>
var url = "template.html";
var externalHtmlContent = $ajax(url).document.getElementById("id").innerHTML;
</script>
```

so `externalHtmlContent` would contain "Content 1" value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    var html = $(data);
    var content_1 = $('#id1', html).text();
    // content_1 is "Content 1"
});
```

Comment: var html="<h1 id='val_h1'>Hello World</h1>";
var content_1=$('#val_h1',html).text();
console.log(content_1);

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="#hiddenDiv" style="display: none"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#hiddenDiv").load(url,
   function() { 
      var content = $('#id1').html();
      //...
   }
);
```